# Facebook fan gate page only working with static pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm building facebook fan gate page in php.
It works 100%, but only with static pages, for example fb.php.
Now I need something like this:

```
FB.php>>>

$id=$_GET['id'];

///and need to put this variable into NEXT and CANCEL url.. something like that

> $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'canvas' => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 1,
            'display' => 'page',
            'req_perms' => 'user_likes',
            'next' => 'somesite.com/FB.php?id=$id',
            'cancel_url'=> 'somesite.com/FB.php?id=$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'canvas' => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 1,
            'display' => 'page',
            'req_perms' => 'user_likes',
            'next' => 'somesite.com/FB.php?id='.$id,
            'cancel_url'=> 'somesite.com/FB.php?id='.$id
```